# Recover data from overwritten EXT4 partition

Tags: linux, debian, ext4

This morning I accidentally re-installed Debian on top of a linux virtual machine (ESX). The original server had an EXT4 partition with some website content on it. I fully completed the installation and now have a blank Debian 8 installation on it.

I have managed to recover a load of files with photorec, but this isnt ideal for a website.

Is there any way to recover the data from this drive?

Comment: How are your backups?

Comment: Non existant on this machine. Its a test box with some content on it. I snapshotted the wrong box before overwriting the OS....